# VST type punning

Tags: c, coq, formal-verification, verifiable-c

C ISO 99 standard supports so-called "type punning". Here is a small example:

```
char *f(const char *x) {
  union {
    const char *x;
    char *y;
  } t;

  t.x = x;

  return t.y;
}
```

As you can see, here we're using union type to get rid of `const` modifier by accessing second field with the same type but without `const`.

VST:

```
Require Import VST.floyd.proofauto.
Require Import example.

Definition Vprog : varspecs. mk_varspecs prog. Defined.
Instance CompSpecs : compspecs. make_compspecs prog. Defined.

Open Scope Z.

Definition f_spec : ident * funspec :=
  DECLARE _f
    WITH x : val
    PRE [tptr tschar]
      PROP ()
      PARAMS (x)
      GLOBALS ()
      SEP (data_at_ Tsh (tptr tschar) x)
    POST [tptr tschar]
      PROP ()
      LOCAL ()
      SEP ().

Definition Gprog := ltac:(with_library prog [f_spec]).

Theorem test : semax_body Vprog Gprog f_f f_spec.
Proof.
  start_function.
  forward.
  forward.
  (* if you run entailer! here, you'll get False, which is unprovable *)
  entailer!.
Admitted.
```

If you run this coq code, you'll get to unprovable goal(mentioned in the comment) where VST checks whether we're trying to get initialized field from union. It looks as follows:

```
  ENTAIL Delta,
  PROP ( )
  LOCAL (lvar _t (Tunion __136 noattr) v_t; temp _x x)
  SEP (data_at Tsh (Tunion __136 noattr) (inl x) v_t; data_at_ Tsh (tptr tschar) x)
  |-- local (liftx (tc_val (tptr tschar) Vundef))
```

which transforms into `False` by `entailer!` tactic.

So, the questions are:
1) Why VST represents unions as disjoint sum?

2) Is this feature(type punning) not supported by VST?

3) Are there any workarounds around this issue excluding editing C code?